# View the innards of a .ppt file?

Tags: html, ms-office

I need to figure out what is going on inside a client's `.ppt` files.  What is a good way to get started?

My eventual hope is to convert it to HTML.  But if I just export the `.ppt` to HTML, I get a lot of images (as opposed to text), which is not a Good Thing.

EDIT: software that automatically converts `.ppt` to HTML would be terrific, provided that it preserves as much information as possible in text format.  If that doesn't exist, the next best thing would be to understand the innards of the `.ppt` and write my own code to do a partial conversion.

EDIT: I used OfficeConvert as recommended by Michiel Leenaars.  It got me text all right.  My 50-page, 8MB test file turned into 40MB of text.  The fact that I got text is good.  The fact that the amount went way up is moving in the wrong direction.  And there is an awful lot of repetition in there.  The word "style" appeared 410815 times; the word "draw" appeared 351229 times.

Comment: Are you looking for software to convert ppt to html, a way to programmatically parse ppt, a description of the format, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a safe way would be to use [OfficeConvert](http://code.officeshots.org./trac/officeshots/browser/trunk/OfficeConvert) to automatically convert to ODF programmatically with Microsoft Office. Run it with `/?` to get help. There are some dependencies (see below).

Then use a good ODF library like [lpod](http://lpod-project.org) to look inside it.

You can view some interesting code examples [here](http://recipes.opendocsociety.org).

---

Dependencies:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5)
- Primary Interop Assemblies for [Office 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=59DAEBAA-BED4-4282-A28C-B864D8BFA513) or [Office 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855v) (whichever you are using).

Comment: I consciously described this as a safe way: it uses Microsoft's own technology to read your document in the legacy (deprecated) ppt format, and writes it out in a standardized file formats supported by Microsoft Office.

Comment: So as the first step in a pipeline, that would qualify as pretty safe. You can then use many libraries (http://opendocsociety.org/tools/odf-tools) to strip out unnecessary markup cruft from MS filters, and combine with something like git. If your requirement is that you need less strict monitoring, many other solutions can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) products. (I'm not associated with them other than as a customer.) I've used the PPT one specifically to write code that pokes around in the insides of a PPT. Overkill if you just want to convert it to HTML, but invaluable for the sorts of things I use it for.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Java, Apache has the [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project which lets you take a look at the inners of a PPT project. Could get all the info you want about the project (images, text) and then convert it to html however you like.

Its free too.